# php SimpleXMLElement set text

Tags: php, xml

how to set text for a SimpleXMLElement in php?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you look at the basic [documentation examples](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)?

From there:

```
include 'example.php';
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

$xml->movie[0]->characters->character[0]->name = 'Miss Coder';

echo $xml->asXML();
```

Comment: what if I need to set an element's text without knowing its parent?  in other words, the element has already being created,perhaps with some attributes.

Comment: For that you use the XPath syntax to make a query like:

foreach ($xml->xpath('//character') as $character) {
    echo $character->name, 'played by ', $character->actor, '<br />';
}

Answer (score 14):

Let's say $node is an SimpleXMLElement. This code:

```
$node->{0} = "some string"
```

will result in an extra childNode in PHP 7, instead of setting the text content for $node. Use:

```
$node[0] = "some string"
```

instead.

Comment: Fab answer for PHP7!

Answer (score 2):

```
$xml = SimpleXMLElement('<a><b><c></c></b></a>');
$foundNodes = $xml->xpath('//c');
$foundNode = $foundNodes[0];
$foundNode->{0} = "This text will be put inside of c tag.";

$xml->asXML(); 
// will output <a><b><c>This text will be put inside of c tag.</c></b></a>
```

More on my search of this answer here:

- [How can I set text value of SimpleXmlElement without using its parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153477/how-can-i-set-text-value-of-simplexmlelement-without-using-its-parent)