# PHP array_walk_recursive() for SimpleXML objects?

Tags: php, simplexml, spl

I would like to apply a function to every node in a SimpleXML object.

```
<api>
   <stuff>ABC</stuff>
   <things>
      <thing>DEF</thing>
      <thing>GHI</thing>
      <thing>JKL</thing>
   </things>
</api>
```

//function reverseText($str){};

```
<api>
   <stuff>CBA</stuff>
   <things>
      <thing>FED</thing>
      <thing>IHG</thing>
      <thing>LKJ</thing>
   </things>
</api>
```

How would I apply reverseText() to every node to get the second XML snippet?

Comment: This must not be recursive but a traversal alongside all elements in *XML document order* could work as well. However in PHP this is implemented as a `RecursiveIterator` in the `SimpleXMLExtension` which can be used as ooutlined by Salathe with the SPL. See as well: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_tree

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here the [Standard PHP Library](http://php.net/spl) can come to the rescue.

One option is to use the (little known) [`SimpleXMLIterator`](http://php.net/simplexmliterator). It is one of several [`RecursiveIterator`](http://php.net/recursiveiterator)s available in PHP and a [`RecursiveIteratorIterator`](http://php.net/recursiveiteratoriterator) from the SPL can be used to loop over and change all of the elements' text.

```
$source = '
<api>
   <stuff>ABC</stuff>
   <things>
      <thing>DEF</thing>
      <thing>GHI</thing>
      <thing>JKL</thing>
   </things>
</api>
';

$xml = new SimpleXMLIterator($source);
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($xml);
foreach ($iterator as $element) {
    // Use array-style syntax to write new text to the element
    $element[0] = strrev($element);
}
echo $xml->asXML();
```

The above example outputs the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<api>
   <stuff>CBA</stuff>
   <things>
      <thing>FED</thing>
      <thing>IHG</thing>
      <thing>LKJ</thing>
   </things>
</api>
```

Comment: I have just tried this to parse an XML file. Be aware that it skips over any elements that contain just other elements, i.e. it only iterates over text elements. In my case I have elements that wrap other elements, but contain attributes that it is important to parse, and this technique does not provide access to them in the loop. For the OP XML this is not a problem. If "thing" had an attribute that needed to be passed to OP's function, then this would not work without some additional XML-structure walking to find the "thing" element.

Comment: The [`RecursiveIteratorIterator`](http://php.net/recursiveiteratoriterator) iterates over leaf nodes only, by default.  You can instruct it to also iterate over non-leaf (parent, branch) nodes by setting the iteration mode (e.g. in the second argument to the constructor... `new RecursiveIteratorIterator($iterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST)`).

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array of all nodes in the document with the [`SimpleXMLElement::xpath()`](http://php.net/SimpleXMLElement.xpath) method.

Then you can use `array_walk` on that array. However you don't want to reverse the string of *every* node, only of those elements which don't have any child elements.

```
$source = '
<api>
   <stuff>ABC</stuff>
   <things>
      <thing>DEF</thing>
      <thing>GHI</thing>
      <thing>JKL</thing>
   </things>
</api>
';    

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($source);

array_walk($xml->xpath('//*'), function(&$node) {
    if (count($node)) return;
    $node[0] = strrev($node);
});

echo $xml->asXML();
```

The above example outputs the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<api>
   <stuff>CBA</stuff>
   <things>
      <thing>FED</thing>
      <thing>IHG</thing>
      <thing>LKJ</thing>
   </things>
</api>
```

The xpath query allows more control for example with namespaces.