# extracting information from xml with php

Tags: php, mysql, xml, parsing

I am trying to write a php script that will pull information from an xml file and place it into a database. I have created a L.A.M.P. stack on CENTOS 6.6. The script below works in the sense that it recognize the total number of inputs in the XML file, but no information is being extracted because each section has sub tags. Is there something I can add to my code to print all sub tags within each tag of input into the database along with its text.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
// sample XML data
$data = <<<XML
<entry type="CVE" name="CVE-2003-0002" seq="2003-0002"
published="2003-01-17" modified="2015-04-14" severity="Medium"
CVSS_version="2.0 incomplete approximation" CVSS_score="5.0"
CVSS_base_score="5.0" CVSS_impact_subscore="2.9"
CVSS_exploit_subscore="10.0" CVSS_vector="(AV:N/AC:L/Au:N/C:P/I:N/A:N)" />
<desc>
<descript source="cve">Multiple ethernet Network Interface 'Card' (NIC)   device drivers do not pad frames with null bytes, which allows remote attackers to obtain information from previous packets or kernel memory by using malformed packets, as demonstrated by Etherleak.
</descript>
</desc>
<loss_types>
<conf/>
</loss_types>
<vuln_types>
<design/>
</vuln_types>
<range>
<network/>
</range>
<refs>
<ref source="CERT-VN" url="http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/412115" adv="1">VU#412115</ref>
<ref source="BUGTRAQ" url="http://www.securityfocus.com/archive/1/archive/1/535181/100/0/threaded">20150402 NEW : VMSA-2015-0003 VMware product updates address critical information disclosure issue in JRE</ref>
<ref source="REDHAT" url="http://www.redhat.com/support/errata/RHSA-2003-025.html">RHSA-2003:025</ref>
<ref source="CONFIRM" url="http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/security/cpujan2015-1972971.html">http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/security/cpujan2015-1972971.html</ref>
<ref source="MISC" url="http://www.atstake.com/research/advisories/2003/atstake_etherleak_report.pdf">http://www.atstake.com/research/advisories/2003/atstake_etherleak_report.pdf</ref>
<ref source="ATSTAKE" url="http://www.atstake.com/research/advisories/2003/a010603-1.txt" adv="1">A010603-1</ref><ref source="FULLDISC" url="http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2015/Apr/5">20150402 NEW : VMSA-2015-0003 VMware product updates address critical information disclosure issue in JRE</ref>
<ref source="MISC" url="http://packetstormsecurity.com/files/131271/VMware-Security-Advisory-2015-0003.html">http://packetstormsecurity.com/files/131271/VMware-Security-Advisory-2015-0003.html</ref><ref source="BUGTRAQ" url="http://marc.theaimsgroup.com/?l=bugtraq&m=104222046632243&w=2" adv="1">20030110 More information regarding Etherleak</ref>
<ref source="VULNWATCH" url="http://archives.neohapsis.com/archives/vulnwatch/2003-q1/0016.html">20030110 More information regarding Etherleak</ref>
<ref source="BUGTRAQ" url="http://www.securityfocus.com/archive/1/archive/1/307564/30/26270/threaded">20030117 Re: More information regarding Etherleak</ref>
<ref source="BUGTRAQ" url="http://www.securityfocus.com/archive/1/archive/1/305335/30/26420/threaded">20030106 Etherleak: Ethernet frame padding information leakage (A010603-1)</ref>
<ref source="REDHAT" url="http://www.redhat.com/support/errata/RHSA-2003-088.html">RHSA-2003:088</ref><ref source="OSVDB" url="http://www.osvdb.org/9962">9962</ref>
<ref source="OVAL" url="http://oval.mitre.org/repository/data/getDef?id=oval:org.mitre.oval:def:2665" sig="1">oval:org.mitre.oval:def:2665</ref>
</refs>
<vuln_soft>
<prod name="freebsd" vendor="freebsd">
<vers num="4.2"/>
<vers num="4.3"/>
<vers num="4.4"/>
<vers num="4.5"/>
<vers num="4.6"/>
<vers num="4.7"/>
</prod>
<prod name="linux_kernel" vendor="linux">
<vers num="2.4.1"/>
<vers num="2.4.10"/>
<vers num="2.4.11"/>
<vers num="2.4.12"/>
<vers num="2.4.13"/>
<vers num="2.4.14"/>
<vers num="2.4.15"/>
<vers num="2.4.16"/>
<vers num="2.4.17"/>
<vers num="2.4.18"/>
<vers num="2.4.19"/>
<vers num="2.4.2"/>
<vers num="2.4.20"/>
<vers num="2.4.3"/>
<vers num="2.4.4"/>
<vers num="2.4.5"/>
<vers num="2.4.6"/>
<vers num="2.4.7"/>
<vers num="2.4.8"/>
<vers num="2.4.9"/>
</prod>
<prod name="windows_2000" vendor="microsoft">
<vers num="" edition=":advanced_server"/> 
<vers num="" edition=":server"/>
<vers num="" edition=":professional"/>
<vers num="" edition=":datacenter_server"/>
<vers num="" edition="sp1:datacenter_server"/>
<vers num="" edition="sp1:advanced_server"/>
<vers num="" edition="sp1:professional"/>
<vers num="" edition="sp1:server"/>
<vers num="" edition="sp2:datacenter_server"/>
<vers num="" edition="sp2:advanced_server"/>
<vers num="" edition="sp2:professional"/>
<vers num="" edition="sp2:server"/>
</prod>
<prod name="windows_2000_terminal_services" vendor="microsoft">
<vers num="" edition="sp1"/>
<vers num="" edition="sp2"/>
</prod>
<prod name="netbsd" vendor="netbsd">
<vers num="1.5"/>
<vers num="1.5.1"/>
<vers num="1.5.2"/>
<vers num="1.5.3"/>
<vers num="1.6"/>
</prod>
</vuln_soft>
</entry>
XML;

// gather XML data

// database connection settings
$host = 'localhost';
$database = 'cve';
$user = 'admin';
$pass = 'admin';
$table = 'vulnerabilities';

try {
// connect to database
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $database, $user, $pass);

// prepare xml and iterator
$xml = new SimpleXMLIterator($data);
$itr = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($xml);
// loop through XML data
foreach ($itr as $key => $value) {

    // prepare an insert statement
    $statement = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO $table (identifier,seq,published,modified,severity,cvss_verison,cvss_score,cvss_base_score,cvss_impact_subscore,cvss_exploit_subscore,cvs_vector,information,loss_types,vuln_types,impact_area,refs,vuln_soft) VALUES (':name',':seq',':published',':modified',':severity',':CVSS_verison',':CVSS_score',':CVSS_base_score',':CVSS_impact_subscore',':CVSS_exploit_subscore',':CVSS_vector',':desc',':loss_types',':vuln_types',':range',':ref',':vuln_soft')");

    // bind your XML data to named parameters for the insert statement
    $statement->bindParam(':name', $value->attributes()->identifier);
    $statement->bindParam(':seq', $value->attributes()->seq);
    $statement->bindParam(':published', $value->attributes()->published);
    $statement->bindParam(':modified', $value->attributes()->modified);
    $statement->bindParam(':severity', $value->attributes()->severity);
    $statement->bindParam(':CVSS_version', $value->attributes()->cvss_verison);
    $statement->bindParam(':CVSS_score', $value->attributes()->cvss_score);
    $statement->bindParam(':CVSS_base_score', $value->attributes()->cvss_base_score);
    $statement->bindParam(':CVSS_impact_subscore', $value->attributes()->cvss_impact_subscore);
    $statement->bindParam(':CVSS_exploit_subscore', $value->attributes()->cvss_exploit_subscore);
    $statement->bindParam(':CVS_vector', $value->attributes()->cvs_vector);
    $statement->bindParam(':desc',$value->attributes()->information);
    $statement->bindParam(':loss_types',$value->attributes()->loss_types);
    $statement->bindParam(':vuln_types',$value->attributes()->vuln_types);
    $statement->bindParam(':range',$value->attributes()->impact_area);
    $statement->bindParam(':refs',$value->attributes()->refs);
    $statement->bindParam(':vuln_soft',$value->attributes()->vuln_soft);


    // insert XML data into database table
    $statement->execute();
}

$dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
print "There was an error: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
die();
}

?>
```

I need to collect all data from entry tag and place it into database.
Example of xml code with information in tag:

```
<entry type="CVE" name="CVE-2003-0001" seq="2003-0001"
 published="2003-01-17" modified="2015-04-14" severity="Medium"
 CVSS_version="2.0 incomplete approximation" CVSS_score="5.0"
 CVSS_base_score="5.0" CVSS_impact_subscore="2.9"
 CVSS_exploit_subscore="10.0" CVSS_vector="(AV:N/AC:L/Au:N/C:P/I:N/A:N)">
```

I then need to collect all data with in entry tag by recording the subtags data and text of the tags with the entry tag.
Example of xml code with sub tags:

```
<refs>
<ref source="reference information">Reference information</ref></refs>
<ref source="reference information">Reference information</ref></refs>
<ref source="reference information">Reference information</ref></refs>
<ref source="reference information">Reference information</ref></refs>
</refs>
</entry>
```

The current script as detailed above return the following warnings and on fatal error:
    PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 6: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document in /home/ant244/Documents/extract.php on line 112

```
PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): <desc> in /home/ant244/Documents/extract.php on line 112

PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): ^ in /home/ant244/Documents/extract.php on line 112

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in /home/ant244/Documents/extract.php:112

Stack trace:
#0 /home/ant244/Documents/extract.php(112):  SimpleXMLElement->__construct('<entry type="CV...')

#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/ant244/Documents/extract.php on line 112
```

Answer (score 0):

### Background

If I'm understanding your question correctly, one approach might involve looping through your XML `entry` data while using the found data pieces as named parameters inside *prepared SQL statements*. Prepared statements can help keep your database input fairly clean *(see the "**How do I make my database queries secure from SQL injection?**" section on the [PHP tag wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info) for more information)*.

This approach might look something like the example code below. The code below shows how *prepared statements* can be used for your database work, and how XML data can be accessed with a `$value->attributes()->name` format inside a `foreach` loop *(where `name` matches individual attributes from your XML entries)*:

### Code Example 1 *(prepared statements)*

```
<?php

// sample XML data
$data = <<<XML
<root>
<entry type="CVE" name="CVE-2003-0001" seq="2003-0001"
published="2003-01-17" modified="2015-04-14" severity="Medium"
CVSS_version="2.0 incomplete approximation" CVSS_score="5.0"
CVSS_base_score="5.0" CVSS_impact_subscore="2.9"
CVSS_exploit_subscore="10.0" CVSS_vector="(AV:N/AC:L/Au:N/C:P/I:N/A:N)" />
<entry type="CVE" name="CVE-2003-0002" seq="2003-0002"
published="2003-01-17" modified="2015-04-14" severity="Medium"
CVSS_version="2.0 incomplete approximation" CVSS_score="5.0"
CVSS_base_score="5.0" CVSS_impact_subscore="2.9"
CVSS_exploit_subscore="10.0" CVSS_vector="(AV:N/AC:L/Au:N/C:P/I:N/A:N)" />
</root>
XML;

// gather XML data
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);

// database connection settings
$host = 'localhost';
$database = 'your_database';
$user = 'your_username';
$pass = 'your_password';
$table = 'your_database_table';

try {
    // connect to database
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $database, $user, $pass);

    // loop through XML data
    foreach ($xml->entry as $key => $value) {

        // prepare an insert statement
        $statement = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO $table (name, seq) VALUES (:name, :seq)");

        // bind your XML data to named parameters for the insert statement
        $statement->bindParam(':name', $value->attributes()->name);
        $statement->bindParam(':seq', $value->attributes()->seq);

        // insert XML data into database table
        $statement->execute();
    }

    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "There was an error: " . $e->getMessage();
    die();
}

?>
```

When it comes to working with nested tags, however, it might be a good idea to use an [iterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php). In the case of your example XML *(simplified for the code example below)* [using an iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17095712/1167750) could look like this:

### Code Example 2 *(iterators)*

```
<?php

// sample XML data
$data = <<<XML
<root>
<entry>
<refs>
<ref source="reference_information_1">Reference information 1</ref>
<ref source="reference_information_2">Reference information 2</ref>
</refs>
</entry>
</root>
XML;

// prepare XML data and iterator
$xml = new SimpleXMLIterator($data);
$itr = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($xml);

// iterate over each relevant tag
foreach ($itr as $key => $value) {
  echo $key . ": " . $value . "\n";
  echo "source attribute: " . $value->attributes()->source . "\n";
}

?>
```

This code produces the following output:

```
ref: Reference information 1
source attribute: reference_information_1
ref: Reference information 2
source attribute: reference_information_2
```

### Code Example 3 *(prepared statements + iterators)*

```
<?php

// sample XML data
$data = <<<XML
<root>
<entry type="CVE" name="CVE-2003-0001" seq="2003-0001"
published="2003-01-17" modified="2015-04-14" severity="Medium"
CVSS_version="2.0 incomplete approximation" CVSS_score="5.0"
CVSS_base_score="5.0" CVSS_impact_subscore="2.9"
CVSS_exploit_subscore="10.0" CVSS_vector="(AV:N/AC:L/Au:N/C:P/I:N/A:N)" />
<entry type="CVE" name="CVE-2003-0002" seq="2003-0002"
published="2003-01-17" modified="2015-04-14" severity="Medium"
CVSS_version="2.0 incomplete approximation" CVSS_score="5.0"
CVSS_base_score="5.0" CVSS_impact_subscore="2.9"
CVSS_exploit_subscore="10.0" CVSS_vector="(AV:N/AC:L/Au:N/C:P/I:N/A:N)" />
</root>
XML;

// database connection settings
$host = 'localhost';
$database = 'your_database';
$user = 'your_username';
$pass = 'your_password';
$table = 'your_database_table';

try {
    // connect to database
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $database, $user, $pass);

    // prepare XML data and iterator
    $xml = new SimpleXMLIterator($data);
    $itr = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($xml);

    // iterate over each relevant tag
    foreach ($itr as $key => $value) {

        // prepare an insert statement
        $statement = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO $table (name, seq) VALUES (:name, :seq)");

        // bind your XML data to named parameters for the insert statement
        $statement->bindParam(':name', $value->attributes()->name);
        $statement->bindParam(':seq', $value->attributes()->seq);

        // insert XML data into database table
        $statement->execute();
    }

    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "There was an error: " . $e->getMessage();
    die();
}

?>
```

### Conclusion

**Prepared statements** and **iterators** can each provide safe and convenient ways to work with XML and database-related applications. In the case of your program, it might be helpful to combine ideas from these two code examples *(by using the `iterators` from the **Second Code Example** for the `// loop through XML data` section of the **First Code Example**)* as shown in the **Third Code Example**.

Comment: Thank you for the post. Can you explain how I would be able to pair the two code examples? I am having trouble understanding how the foreach statement would look like if I used an iterators to place all information within tags into there proper places in a database.

Comment: @asingletonCT I've updated this answer with a third code example that combines the earlier two code examples. Let me know if this helps!

Comment: I've updated my code to reflect your answer. Once I run the script is get a couple warnings and one fatal error which I have placed at the bottom of the question.

Comment: @asingletonCT This problem is related to how you are using `<desc>` parameters for those last few lines of the `$statement->bindParam()` database part... what information exactly are you looking to get from the `<desc>` tags? Those parameters also need to be titled with a leading `:` if anything. Otherwise, you'll continue to get the same kind of errors.

Comment: I am trying to collect the text that is related to each "subtag" of the entry and place it into a column of a database. For example one row would be one entry with its information about the vulnerability spread across the columns for that single row. The script above holds one XML entry I have an XML file that holds thousands of these entries and I would like to put it into an MySQL database so I create different tables based on queries.

Comment: @asingletonCT Have you tried using named parameters for the `<desc>` (and following) tags?

Comment: I have not used named parameters. Is that something that is done in XML coding or in PHP coding?

Comment: @asingletonCT You have used named parameters for the `:name` type of labels on the lines like this: `$statement->bindParam(':name', ...)`. In order to avoid the errors from earlier, try changing the parameters that have `<...>` into something like `:...` (where `...` is the name of your parameter).

Comment: I changed all the <..> to simply :.. (contents of the previous <..> I now get an error at line 20 stating that PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 6719: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in extract.php on line 20. I do not have experience in php so I am having difficulty debugging the issue.

Comment: @asingletonCT Please update the code in your question above to match your current working code...

Comment: my edits have been posted. If this script works with the one entry that is hard written into the code, I would like to replace that with the location of the actual XML file.

Comment: @asingletonCT Are you sure the XML in your code is valid? You might want to try running the XML through an online validation website (try searching for something like "xml validator").

Answer (score 0):

```
if( get_class( $itrXml ) == 'SimpleXMLIterator' ) { # when the thing is a SimpleXMLIterator
  print $itrXml->__toString( );                     # output its string value
```

This applies only if $itrXml is a leaf     -node with zero children.

This fails        if $itrXml is a branching-node with some children, with "Error: Call to a member function __toString() on array"