# setting content of Simplexml node

Tags: php, simplexml

I have a DomElement

```
<title>
   <language id="1" />
   <language id="2" />
</title>
```

I want to set the content of both languages

```
$node=$pp->title
foreach($node->language as $lang) {
    $lang->nodeValue="Default";
}
```

I presumed I had to use ->nodevalue as I do when getting.
This gives

```
 <title>
   <language id="1"><nodeValue>Default</nodeValue></language>
   <language id="2"><nodeValue>Default</nodeValue></language>
</title>
```

So I tried

```
$node=$pp->title
foreach($node->language as $lang) {
    $lang="Default";
}
```

This does not change the value.

I wanted

```
 <title>
   <language id="1">Default</language>
   <language id="2">Default</language>
</title>
```

It is probably something very simple I'm overlooking...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set text value of SimpleXmlElement without using its parent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153477/how-can-i-set-text-value-of-simplexmlelement-without-using-its-parent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set to the element itself (not to the variable).

```
foreach($node->language as $lang) {
    $lang->{0} = "Default";
}
```

Comment: You answered at the same time as I found the answer elsewhere ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here:

[How can I set text value of SimpleXmlElement without using its parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153477/how-can-i-set-text-value-of-simplexmlelement-without-using-its-parent)

```
$node=$pp->title
foreach($node->language as $lang) {
    $lang[0]="Default";
}
```